# Nodemailer issues with private host

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer, starttls

I am using nodemailer to send emails with some private host. Here is my code:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 host: "smtp.abc.net",
 secure: false,
 port: 587,
 auth: {
    user: "example@example.com",
    pass: "password"
 }
});
```

It was getting certificates issues so I tried adding certificates but again there was an error - 'Must issue a STARTTLS command first'

I added an option -

```
tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}
```

And it worked. But I am not sure is it a good way to set rejectUnauthorized to false. 
What are the impacts of doing this? Is there any alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same error with "secure: true" option ?

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'poczta.o2.pl',
    port: 465,  
    secure: true, // secure:true for port 465, secure:false for port 587
    auth: {
        user: process.env.MAILING_USER,
        pass: process.env.MAILING_USER_PASSWORD
    }
});
```

Comment: yes I was getting the same error with setting secure to true

Answer (score 0):

I added 4 options : ssl, ignoreTLS, requireTLS, rejectUnauthorized. And it worked. Seems like the problem was with NoSSL. I turned SSL off and added TLS.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: "example.com",
secure: false,
port: 587,
ssl: false,
ignoreTLS: false,
requireTLS: true,
auth: {
    user: "user@email.com",
    pass: "password"
},
tls: {
  secureProtocol: "TLSv1_2_method",
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}});
```